# HashBasedTable in Spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, guava

I've written successfully to read table in spring.xml as below.

```
<bean id="kpTable" class="com.kp.util.MultiMapToTableConverter" factory-method="createTableFactory"
        scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg name="map">
            <util:map>
                <entry key="usa">
                    <util:map>
                        <entry key="alabama" value="Montgomery" />
                        <entry key="Arizona" value="Phoenix" />
                        <entry key="Arkansas" value="Little Rock" />
                        <entry key="California" value="Sacramento" />
                        <entry key="Colorado" value="Denver" />
                    </util:map>
                </entry>
                <entry key="uk">
                    <util:map>
                        <entry key="Yorkshire" value="York" />
                        <entry key="Norfolk" value="Norwich" />
                        <entry key="Oxfordshire " value="Oxford" />
                        <entry key="Northamptonshire " value="Northampton" />
                        <entry key="Nottinghamshire " value="Nottingham" />
                    </util:map>
                </entry>
                <entry key="in">
                    <util:map>
                        <entry key="maharashtra" value="mumbai" />
                        <entry key="karnataka" value="bangalore" />
                        <entry key="tamil nadu" value="chennai" />
                        <entry key="west bengal " value="kolkata" />
                    </util:map>
                </entry>
            </util:map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

**MultiMapToTableConverter.java**

```
public class MultiMapToTableConverter {

    public static Table<String, String, String> createTableFactory(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {

        Table<String, String, String> table = HashBasedTable.create();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> outerEntrySet : map.entrySet()) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> innerEntrySet : outerEntrySet.getValue().entrySet()) {
                table.put(outerEntrySet.getKey(), innerEntrySet.getKey(), innerEntrySet.getValue());
            }
        }
        return table;
    }

}
```

**MyTest class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:spring-kp-context.xml"})
public class KPTableTest {

    @Autowired
    private Table<String, String, String> table;

    @Test
    public void kpTest(){
        System.out.println(table.get("usa", "alabama"));
        System.out.println(table.get("in", "karnataka"));
        System.out.println(table.get("in", "tamil nadu"));
}
```

Now I've some question based on the implementation

1. As per below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897335/define-guava-hashbasedtable-table-in-spring-xml-config) the answer is downvoted. Is there something wrong.
2. Is there any bottleneck in the implemenation, I know HashBasedTable is unsynced but I don't have any issue. as I know my table is not going to change.
3. From Performance perspective which is better `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` Vs `HashBasedTable`.
4. May be this a broader question, however Is there any limitation of HashBasedTable?